# Why does Webkit/Safari (iOS, macOS) render my SVG transformations in a different order compared to Blink and Gecko?

Tags: svg, safari, webkit, chromium

I have a minimal SVG image of an asterisk icon:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
        <style>
        .a {
            fill: red;
            transform-box: fill-box;
            transform-origin: center;
        }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <!-- x = 45 because it's 10px wide and centered around x=50, so x0 == 45, x1 == 55 -->
    <rect class="a" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100"/>
    <rect class="a" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate(-45)"/>
    <rect class="a" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate( 45)"/>
    <rect class="a" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate(-90)"/>
</svg>
```

This renders correctly in Firefox 75 and Chrome 80, but not Safari on iOS nor macOS:

#### Firefox 75:

[image]

#### Chrome 80:

[image]

#### Safari on iOS 13

But on Safari, the `transform-origin` is seemingly ignored, or applied out-of-order compared to the `transform=""` attribute on each of the `<rect>` elements:

[image]

I'm told it renders the same broken image on macOS Safari (I don't have immediate access to macOS Safari right now so I can't post a screenshot from there, sorry).

I've searched around Google to see if Safari/WebKit is lacking support for [`transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box), [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) or [`transform="rotate(deg)"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) but as far as I can tell they've all been fully supported by Safari for years - so I don't understand why it's applying the transformations out-of-order and causing the broken rendering.

Comment: presumably safari doesn't support transform-origin or transform-box on SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson But both MDN and CanIUse.com report Safari supports `transform-origin` and `transform-box` for SVG, with no annotations or other notes regarding differences in behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson It looks like the documentation is only technically correct - it seems Safari does support the `transform-origin` CSS property in SVG, but it doesn't use it for `transform=""` chains, which is weird (and contrary to all other browsers too...)

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm submitting a PR to MDN's browser compatibility database to improve the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling with the SVG in Safari, Safari's Web Inspector **does** seem to recognize the `transform-origin` SVG style property, but it doesn't actually use it when applying transformations, which is weird (e.g. using `transform-origin: center;` or `transform-origin: 0px 0px` or `transform-origin: 50px 50px` had no effect) - so a fix lies in changing the rotation centre using some other means.

As far as I can tell, macOS Safari and iOS Safari both only use `transform-origin` for CSS-based transformations using the `transform` property and **not** when using SVG attribute-based transformations using `transform=""` - whereas Blink and Gecko both use `transform-origin` for both attribute-based and CSS-based transformations.

### Using a `translate` step

One approach is to add a `translate` step so the centre of rotation is centred in the canvas, then perform the rotation, then undo the `translate` step:

```
transform="translate( 50, 50 ) rotate(45) translate( -50, -50 )"
```

Like so:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
    <rect fill="red"    x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" />
    <rect fill="blue"   x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-45) translate(-50,-50)" />
    <rect fill="green"  x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="translate(50,50) rotate( 45) translate(-50,-50)" />
    <rect fill="orange" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="translate(50,50) rotate(-90) translate(-50,-50)" />
</svg>
```

#### Better approach: Using `rotate( angle, x, y )`:

Rather than applying an initial `translate` step to the `transform` chain, [I saw that the `rotate` transformation function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Rotate) supports specifying a centre-of-rotation using additional arguments - so this works in Safari, Chrome (+Edge +Opera), and Firefox:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
    <rect fill="red"    x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" />
    <rect fill="blue"   x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate(-45, 50, 50)" />
    <rect fill="green"  x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate( 45, 50, 50)" />
    <rect fill="orange" x="45" y="0" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate(-90, 50, 50)" />
</svg>
```